# Database structure for location

Tags: sql, database, normalization, database-normalization

I have 3 tables -

**Countries**
CountryId | Name

**States**
StateId | Name | CountryId

**Cities**
CityId | Name | StateId

These 3 fields are referenced in user table (and some other tables).

**Users**
UserId | Name | CountryId | StateId | CityId

Only country is mandatory. State and City are nullable. 
We will show state field only when country is updated, and then show city when state is updated. Ex:

UserID | Name | CountryId | StateId | CityId

abc    | xyz  | 1         | null    | null

abc1   | xyz1 | 1         | 19      | null

abc2   | xyz2 | 9         | 2       | 34

Also, I have to list down Countries in a lot of places.. And also I have some tables where only Country field is referenced. for ex:

**Presidents**
PresidentId | Country

---

A different approach that I thought of is -

**Locations**
LocationId(Autoincrement int) | Country(string) | State(string) | City(string)

**Users**
UserId | Name | LocationId

---

Which approach is good? 
Please suggest me if there is a better way of structuring the db?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach is better, because in the second one you'll have multiple copies of country for each city, for example. But, for user it's enough to specify the cityId, because you can figure out the state and country from it.
Also, note that the standard specifies to use nouns at singular for entity names.

Comment: Thanks Paul92. I updated the question mentioning that State, City are nullable. In this case, having only CityId in the users table wont work, right?

Comment: just to add to that `singular for entity names` is not THE but A standard ;) Its the trade were you prefer to read ugly stuff; in my opinion `SELECT * FROM Item` reads uglier than `SELECT * FROM Items` but singular-name-defending guys will most rightly point to history or link tables that then may contain two pluralized names such as `ItemsRelations` or such (which on the other hand could be prevented by some additional conventions ;))